# Do I have to delete these pointers?

Tags: c++, qt

This is the `MainWindow` class which I call and use the function `show()` to make it visible to the user.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QGridLayout* gridLayout;
    QGridLayout* infoBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout* buttonGroup;
    QHBoxLayout* subCategoryLayout;
    //... more widgets

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setupUi();
    void setupConnections();

private slots:
    void add();
    void edit();
    void remove();
    void find();
    void clearAll();
    void screenshotDesktop();
    void screenshotApp();

    void currentSubCategoryChanged( const QString& );
    void curretCategoryChanged( const int );

    void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * );

};
```

I created for each widget (those pointers after the macro `Q_OBJECT`) a new object on the heap with `new`. However, I did not delete them anywhere in the program. Does this cause a memory leak in Qt? Or does something from Qt delete them automatically when destroying the class?

Comment: What did you pass as a first argument to the constructor of these objects?

Comment: If you are adding these to the layout, the parent ( MainWindow) will have the responsibility of releasing the memory.

Comment: Note: it's a good practice to wrap such pointers to QPointer class. No changes of code are required, but you will be protected from accessing to invalid pointers.

Answer (score 14):

If a widget has a parent set, then Qt will handle deleting the widget.
In the case of a MainWindow, when you close it, the MainWindow and its children will be cleaned up, so pass the parent to the widget's constructor: -

```
QHBoxLayout* buttonGroup = new QHBoxLayout(this); // where this is the parent (MainWindow)
```

If you create a Widget such as this: -

```
QHBoxLayout* buttonGroup = new QHBoxLayout;
```

And haven't passed in the parent, then it will not be cleaned up and you'll have to handle that yourself.

Comment: The parent doesn't have to be specified at creation time - a widget can also be added as a child later.

Comment: Alright. When I set the parent, is deleting them manually still okay or just unnecessary? Just to be on the safe side, I don't want memory leaks in my program.

Comment: @Davlog If you set the parent, you must *not* delete them manually. You only delete what you own. The Qt parent-child scheme includes ownership. Once you set a widget's parent, you don't own it, its parent does.

Comment: @Davlog if the UI has deleted the widget and you delete again your program will end up in undefined behavior (eg. a crash)

Comment: @DieterLücking but Qt is pretty smart about destroyed objects: they (and the children) are automatically removed from the hierarchy and all connections removed

Comment: @ratchetfreak If the pointer is kept, that pointer will not become zero - hence: double deletion

Comment: @Merlin069: It's not true that merely *creating* parentless QObjects (here: QWidgets) will lead to a memory leak. Qt is often reparenting such objects for you. For example, adding a widget to a layout will reparent it to the underlying widget, either right away if the layout is set on a widget, or later whenever the layout is added to a widget.

Comment: @KubaOber, correct and that's why I stated 'If a widget has a parent set, then Qt will handle deleting the widget', but I see your point that you're emphasising that the parent can be set after object creation.

Comment: Is there a reference for this?

Answer (score 5):

if you add them to the gui hierarchy then they will be cleaned up when the `MainWindow` is deleted

this is because parents assume ownership over their children (which is set with the various adds of the gui)

so a `this->add(centralWidget);` will call `centralWidget->setParent(this);` which will let `centralWidget` be deleted when `MainWindow` is deleted

you are free to delete QObjects yourself but beware dangling pointers (QPointer will help here). though I suggest using `deleteLater()` to ensure no strange behavior when a pointer still lives on the stack.

for more info about the object tree see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/objecttrees.html)

Answer (score 2):

The automatic memory management through parent-child relationships is done by the `QObject`. `QWidget` happens to be a `QObject`, and it so happens that widgets that have parent widgets have the same underlying QObjects as parents.

A QObject with children automatically deletes its children in its destructor.

A QObject or a QWidget may be adopted by another object. For example, adding widgets to a layout will automatically reparent them to the widget the layout is set on. Even if a layout doesn't have a widget set on it yet, the reparenting will be done at the time you add the layout to a widget (or to a layout that has a widget set). It's pretty clever and saves a lot of typing and reduces possibilities for mistakes.

The idiomatic, minimum-typing way of adding widgets to another widget is:

```
MyWidget() {
  QLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout(this); // set a layout on this widget
  layout->addWidget(new QLabel("foo")); // the label is reparented to this
  layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("bar")); // the button is reparented to this
}
```